# systemd container: how can I automatically run a bash script?

Tags: bash, docker, systemd

After successfully following these [RHEL systemd container instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/managing_containers/using_systemd_with_containers), I'd  now like the container, every time it starts, to run a bash script. However, I'd like it to run **only once**. That doesn't seem like a "service" to me. I don't want to start the container, then manually run the bash script (e.g., docker exec -it ...). Should I make a systemd unit file to start the script and then disable the service in my bash script? That seems a bit like a hack, no?

Update: To answer commenters, the bash script requires systemd. So first systemd must start, then the script runs, installs software, and then issues systemctl start commands. Yes, I know what you're thinking: install the software using RUN and then let systemd start it, but unfortunately, I can't do that for this project. The script, which I didn't write, expects systemd to be running. Also, the script does run inside the container, in a named volume.

Comment: only once per container start?

Comment: and from your reference to `docker exec` this script is inside the container?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't simply modify the container to execute that script as part of its startup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a systemd unit file of service type `oneshot` for your bash script. The `oneshot` type represents short-lived process, usually run as one-off task. systemd waits for the process to exit before continuing on with other units.

For example,

```
[Unit]
Description=my only-once script

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /path/to/only_once_script.sh
RemainAfterExit=true
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note that `RemainAfterExit` must be set to `true` if you want systemd to consider the service as *active* after the start action completed successfully.

Take a look at *Example 2* and *Example 3* in the systemd [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).

Comment: in my case, the script will take 20 minutes and I don't want to block/prevent the loading of other services. Can I set ExecStart=/bin/bash /some/script.sh & to run it in the background?

Comment: No, `&` isn't supported by any of the `ExecStart=`, `ExecStartPre=`, `ExecStartPost=`, `ExecReload=`, `ExecStop=`, and `ExecStopPost=` options, as said in the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) under _Command lines_.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need "systemd" because the installer program runs "systemctl start" commands then may be you can avoid the fuzz by using the [systemctl-docker-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) wrapper.

I am regurlarly using it to overwrite /usr/bin/systemctl in which case "systemctl start" is executed correctly without any systemd daemon running. Tested with quite a number of installer programs to mimic the behaviour that they expect from "systemctl start".

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in your same service itself. Consider the below flow on my machine

```
$ docker run -d ubuntu:16.04 sleep 200
2e76d13cee285143dc91af0e6ddbd51bd31e92d7baa3ec34638726cdd0abb572

$ docker exec -d 2e76d13cee285143dc91af0e6ddbd51bd31e92d7baa3ec34638726cdd0abb572 sleep 300

$ docker exec  2e76d13cee285143dc91af0e6ddbd51bd31e92d7baa3ec34638726cdd0abb572 ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.2  0.0   4384   756 ?        Ss   12:25   0:00 sleep 200
root         5  0.1  0.0   4384   792 ?        Ss   12:25   0:00 sleep 300
root         9  0.0  0.2  34428  2740 ?        Rs   12:25   0:00 ps aux
```

As you can see i executed a command in background (-d/--detach of exec command)

So in your Service file. Just define the `ExecStartPost=` in your main unit which launches the docker container and use `exec` with `-d` flag